# libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open radeonsi (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)

Tags: drivers, radeon, amd-graphics, opengl

tried to run VirtScreen and after executing it showed the error

`libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open radeonsi (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)`

ubuntu 20.04.1
AMD fx-8800
radeon r8 m350dx

Comment: Is `libgl1-mesa-dri` installed?

Comment: ajgringo619 yes its installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced same error for ANSYS2020R1 which was rectified by installing appropriate driver from amd website.

https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20

Comment: made a 100% incorrect install and it worked XD...thank you so much sir