# "MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast:" -- Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

So, I've installed ANSYS Fluent on Ubuntu 20.04, but although it opens a window, the graphics window stays empty.
On the console, I'm getting these messages:

```bash
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

So, I checked if those three libraries were actually missing, but the first search path is correct. Both `iris_dri.so` and `swrast_dri.so` happily reside in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/` -- but not in `/usr/lib/dri/`, which is what the message seems to complain about.

I'm stumped how it could happen that they're not found although they're clearly on the search path -- and of course I'd like to know what to do about it.

I've found several similar problems which went back to either packages missing, having been replaced or library files being in the wrong place (or some software looking in the wrong place), but here it seems that `MESA-LOADER` is staring right at them but believes they were not what it's looking for?

There's probably some useful information missing here, but I wouldn't know what else could be relevant, so please ask if you think that's the case. Some standard system info:

- I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 (running KDE)
- `mesa-utils` and `libgl1-mesa-dri` are installed (21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2, re-installed following recommendations [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412683/ubuntu-20-04-libgl-error-failed-to-load-driver-swrast))
- I'm on a laptop using an intel 915 GPU, and `i915_dri.so` is also installed and present in the same place as the other libraries.

** Other things I've tried, which don't seem to help **

- [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352158/libgl-error-failed-to-load-drivers-iris-and-swrast-in-ubuntu-20-04) it is suggested to set an environment variable to override the default driver to be specific with the graphics chipset. However, `MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i915 ./fluent` produces exactly the same error message as before.
- One of the replies to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279974/libgl-error-mesa-loader-failed-to-open-radeonsi-search-paths-usr-lib-x86-64) suggests that installing the AMD drivers (even though they're the wrong ones!) helped. In my case, this caused the error message to change, to `failed to open i965 (search paths /opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri)` (interesting, so now it knows to look for intel drivers, but the search path is wrong...), and after removing the AMD drivers again, things changed back to what they were. I tried the same trick with the intel graphics drivers (`xserver-xorg-video-intel` and `i965-va-driver`, also tried `i965-va-driver-shaders` as an alternative), but that changed nothing, and the error message stayed what it was at the beginning.

I'm not sure what else may influence the choice of driver and driver search path, so further suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same MESA-LOADER failure (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, AMD® Ryzen 7 pro 4750u), but with the swrast and radeonsi drivers. The divers were at the right place, but stayed undetected somehow. I created symlinks for both and it solved the issue :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so /usr/lib/dri/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_dri.so /usr/lib/dri/
```

The procedure is indicated here :
https://forum.step.esa.int/t/snap9-error-libegl-warning-mesa-loader-failed-to-open-swrast/36702/5

Comment: Thanks! This helped with ICEM. I linked the DRI driver path to `/user/lib/dri`,  got an error from ICEM's included `libstdc++.so.6`, and replaced that with a link, too. I sure hope that won't cause issues if ICEM also uses it for other purposes and something isn't quite compatible... for Fluent, however, that trick only removed some of the messages I'm getting. There has to be something else wrong on top of this. Also, there must be some way to configure the environment so that the search path is correct to begin with .. I just don't know how. Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` seems useless here.

Comment: yep, I also tried creating a symlink to /usr/lib/dri for swrast_dri.so and then got a different error from `libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found`.  so seems like a problem that symlinks aren't going to solve completely.  something else is not configured correctly.  I encountered this error when running matlab on ubuntu 22.04 with the -nosoftwareopengl option in a remote desktop session and with nvidia drivers.